# Smallest normal extension of F containing E is composite of E and all its conjugates over F. Proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let E be a finite extension of F. Let E=E1,E2,...,Er be all the distinct conjugates of E over F. Prove that the composite K=E1E2...Er is the smallest normal extension of F containing E.

Would anyone know how to attempt this problem/solve it?

Comment: (a) Show $K$ _is_ a normal extension of $F$ containing $E$; (b) Show if $L$ is any normal extension of $F$ and $E \subseteq L$ then $K \subseteq L$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand how to do part a), it is part b) which I have a problem with. Could you help me understand how to prove it?

Comment: By the minimality property of the composite, it suffices to show each $E_i \subseteq L$.

Comment: Could you post an answer showing proof?

Comment: Please does anyone have an answer to this question